# mySQL: selecting based on several keys in key/value table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and trying to select values from one of my own tables that correspond to values in the native wp_postmeta table.

My table is called "wellwishertable" and I would like to find all the ID's (so I can count them) from the wellwisher table where...

1) The wellwishertable 'associatedID' field is in wp_postmeta post_id

2) The wellwishertable 'associatedAuthorID' is the same as a $userID variable

3) The wellwishertable 'permission' is pending

4) The wp_postmeta meta_key 'status' is NOT equal to meta_value 'open'

5) The wp_postmeta meta_key 'freeze' is NOT equal to meta_value 'frozen'

I've got this far...

```
    "SELECT DISTINCT wellwisher.ID FROM wellwishertable wellwisher 
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wellwisher.associatedID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_postmeta.post_id = mt1.post_id) 
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_postmeta.post_id = mt2.post_id) 

    WHERE wellwisher.associatedAuthorID=".$userID." 
    AND wellwisher.permission ='pending' 
    AND ( (mt1.meta_key = 'status' AND mt1.meta_value != 'open') AND 
          (mt2.meta_key = 'freeze' AND mt2.meta_value != 'frozen') );
```

This seems to be 'nearly' working except it doesn't count records that don't have a "freeze" meta_key in the wp_postmeta table. I want it to count any record that isn't "frozen" regardless of whether it exists or not (as long as 'status' isn't 'open').

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` on `mt2`, as `INNER JOIN` will only return results that have an entry there.

In order to avoid requiring `mt2.meta_key` to always have to equal `freeze`, move that condition up to the `ON` clause in your join.

You could also consider using `COUNT` directly in your query rather than figuring it out later:

```
"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT wellwisher.ID) FROM wellwishertable wellwisher 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wellwisher.associatedID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_postmeta.post_id = mt1.post_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_postmeta.post_id = mt2.post_id) 
    AND mt2.meta_key = 'freeze'

WHERE wellwisher.associatedAuthorID=".$userID." 
AND wellwisher.permission ='pending' 
AND ( (mt1.meta_key = 'status' AND mt1.meta_value != 'open') AND 
      (mt2.meta_value != 'frozen') );
```

**IMPORTANT:**
Dumping your `$userID` directly into your query string could be a big security issue. Please consider using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: that's looking really good thanks. There is still a slight issue however, it seems that if there isn't a meta_key value of "freeze" then it doesn't count it (i.e. if there's no meta_key of freeze I would like that to count as a record that doesn't match 'frozen'). Is there something that can be changed to make this work? Thanks :-)

Comment: @JohnT sorry, missed that. Please see how I've moved the `mt2.meta_key = 'freeze'` up into the `JOIN` clause. Now `mt2.meta_value != 'frozen'` should pass when there is no record.

Comment: Great stuff that's working a treat now. Thank you! :-) Thanks for the tip about the variable in the query. The user ID is generated by me but it is very important point with regards santising data before putting it in a query. Thanks again :-)

Comment: oops might have spoken too soon. It works great when 'freeze' is set to 'frozen' but still doesn't work when there is no 'freeze' meta_key? Even if 'status' isn't 'open' if there is no 'freeze' meta_key I'm getting no results? Any other ideas...? I could possibly re-write to always have a 'freeze' key but would be good if there was a way to achieve it with the query? Thanks